# ¿Cómo puedo generar un random de una lista sin que se repita utilizando choice?

Tags: python, lista, windows, random, modulos

¿Cómo puedo agregar una lista auxiliar para llevar el registro de los nombres que ya se han generado: si no está en la lista, generar; en caso contrario, omitir?

Mi código:

```
from random import choice

regalos=['sartén', 'jamón', 'mp4', 'muñeca', 'tv',
    'patín', 'balón', 'reloj', 'bicicleta', 'anillo']

regalos1=[]#Esta es la lista auxiliar, pero no sé como implementarla para verificar lo que ya se ha generado aleatoriamente

up=0
for i in range(5):
    reg=choice(regalos)
    up+=1
    print(f'Regalo {up} : {reg}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es preguntar primero si `reg` está en la lista `regalos1`. Si no está, entonces tienes un nuevo regalo no repetido: lo agregas a la lista `regalos1` y lo muestras.

Si ya está en `regalos1`, simplemente procedes

Para preguntar si el regalo esta en `regalos1`, usas el operador `in`, que prueba si el elemento está en la lista.

También tenemos que cambiar el `for i in range(5)`, debido a que tenemos que realizar más de cinco intentos para formar la lista, dado que es posible encontrar duplicados.

Lo más fácil entonces es contar cuantos regalos tenemos registrado en `regalos1`, y terminar cuando hayamos completado la cuenta. Asi nos deshacemos de la variable `up`

```
from random import choice

regalos=['sartén', 'jamón', 'mp4', 'muñeca', 'tv',
    'patín', 'balón', 'reloj', 'bicicleta', 'anillo']

regalos1=[]#Esta es la lista auxiliar, pero no sé como implementarla para verificar lo que ya se ha generado aleatoriamente

while len(regalos1) < 5:
    reg=choice(regalos)
    if reg not in regalos1:
        regalos1.append(reg)
        print(f'Regalo {len(regalos1)} : {reg}')
```

produce:

```
Regalo 1 : balón
Regalo 2 : bicicleta
Regalo 3 : muñeca
Regalo 4 : patín
Regalo 5 : jamón
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya entendí cómo implementar una lista auxiliar. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el método `sample` del módulo `random`:

```
import random

regalos = [
        'sartén',
        'jamón',
        'mp4',
        'muñeca',
        'tv',
        'patín',
        'balón',
        'reloj',
        'bicicleta',
        'anillo'
]

up = 0

for regalo in random.sample(regalos, 5):
    up += 1
    print(f'Regalo {up} : {regalo}')
```

De esta manera, siempre te imprime elementos que no son repetidos:

```
Regalo 1 : mp4
Regalo 2 : balón
Regalo 3 : sartén
Regalo 4 : muñeca
Regalo 5 : jamón
```

Tienes más información en el siguiente enlace: [random.sample](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-random-sample-function/)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! sí había resuelto el problema utilizando sample, pero en este caso solo quería saber cómo implementar otra lista auxiliar para llevar el registro que ya se generaron previamente, aún así muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, Ulises. Me alegro que lo hayas entendido. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que trataba de hacer por mi cuenta es este código para que con el método `sample` del módulo `random` no se repita y además con una lista auxiliar evitar crear dos bucles for y determinar si en el lista auxiliar está repetido o no.

Comment: Aquí el código: https://imgur.com/rxTO55Z.jpg, Salduos!